# wordpress (elementor) how to insert content from one page into another

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, blogs, elementor

i'm trying to set up an archive page using wordpress (with elementor) that lists 3 other articles (all blog posts but could be normal static pages).  the archive page is to have basic info of its own then summary versions of the 3 articles below it, each with "read more" links that link to the full page versions (the usual thing).  this is the intention anyway.  elementor says i need pro version to do this, astra theme also seems to want this.  i haven't been using wordpress very long & am not yet familiar with the php templating side of it am trying to avoid it if possible as i just want to hurry up & finish this site.  but if i must i'll get into the php.

anyway, any assistance would be helpful.  even if it's just clarifying what i'm not understanding at the moment.  cheers in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

After developing hundreds of websites with Astra and Elementor, I can confirm your suspicion.  And even if you do have the PRO version of Elementor, you are still incredibly limited in designing the "Archive Layout" as elementor only supports 1 block for the "post listings".

TL;DR: Elementor Anywhere will let you create highly reusable templates/themes to circumvent PRO features, and add much more granular customization of elements in "The Loop".

Comment: cheers chris.  ended up using one of astra's starter templates & am in the process of hacking together an archive page to it (at least that's how it feels).  interesting process learning to work with wordpress & its plugins